# React Native - Fit image to screen

Tags: image, react-native

I just want to fit an image of any size to the phone screen, so it just stays there as a background. I have the same issue with a logo I'm trying to put in the footer, I can't get it to fit in the it's view container.

I've tried many solutions I found in similar questions, using resizeMode and many width/height values, but nothing seems to work. My image is always displayed the same way.

Code for the image component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'; 


const Workspace = (props) => {

return (
  <View 
  style = {styles.workspaceStyle}>
    <Image
    source={props.img}
    resizeMode = 'contain'/> 
    {props.children}
  </View>
 );
};
const styles = {
  workspaceStyle: {
    flex: 1
 }
}

export default Workspace;
```

My app.js render and style code:

```
render() { 
    return (
        <View style = {{flex: 1}}>

          <Workspace 
            img={require('./images/quarto.png')}/>

          <ScrollView>
            <Header>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
              <HeaderItem img={require('./images/camera.png')}/>
            </Header>
          </ScrollView>

          <ScrollView style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            {this.sideMenuShow()}
          </ScrollView>

          <Footer>
            <View style = {styles.logoContainerStyle}>
              <Image
                style = {styles.logoStyle}
                source = {require('./images/magicalStage.png')}
                resizeMethod = "scale"
                />
            </View>
            <Text style = {{color: 'white', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 2}}>teste, teste, teste, teste</Text>
          </Footer>

        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  logoContainerStyle: {
    marginRight: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginTop: 2,
    marginBottom: 3,
    width: "20%"
  },

  logoStyle: {
   paddingLeft: 2,
   paddingRight: 2 
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

[image: Original picture]

[image: This is what the app is looking like]

Answer (score 8):

In `app.js`, your outer `view` need to use `width and height` of the screen:

```
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
height: Dimensions.get('window').height
```

Next, in `Workspace`: use `stretch` instead of `contain` ( same for your footer, add `resizeMode` )

```
resizeMode: 'stretch',
```

Comment: I'm getting the error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.Dimensions.get')

Comment: import `Dimensions` ( import {View, Image, Dimensions} from 'react-native'; )

Comment: The image is still looking exactly the same, it's not scaling to adapt to the view.

Comment: take a screen shot and add to the question please

Comment: your problem here is because you set `workspace` in the view and equal with `ScrollView and Footer` so it takes leftover spaces after showing `ScrollView and Footer`. You could do as user `Andrea` suggest or use `ImageBackground` from react-native or put all `ScrollView and Footer` inside `workspace`

Comment: It's not working again, the image never changes. I've tried taking all the other components out and leave just the workplace but it doesn't change at all. I'll get into @Andrea solution and try to make it work.

Comment: Here is an example how to use `ImageBackground` https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/imagebackground-example

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm struggling with image resizing options being ignored right now too.

Answer (score 2):

I do mine like this:

**BackgroundImageStyle.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0
  }, 
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  }
})
```

**BacgroundImage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'
import styles from './BackgroundImageStyle'

export default class BackgroundImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={this.props.source}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

then you can use it like

```
<BackgroundImage source={your_image}/>
```

I hope everything is clear, the trick is to set position absolute and then top, left, bottom, and right to 0

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but it's not working with my code. I'll still get back to it if I can't solve it with the solution I'm trying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ImageBackground component from react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground

```
return (
  <ImageBackground source={...} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```